# TeX compilers cannot find mathematica Pygments style

Tags: minted, paths, pygments

I am trying to compile a `.tex` file and typeset some Mathematica code using the `minted` package. I get the following error:

```
(./out/_minted-thesis/mathematica.pygstyle)Could not find style module 'pygments.styles.mathematica'.
 (./out/_minted-thesis/mathematica.pygstyle)

! Package minted Error: Cannot find Pygments style mathematica.
```

The preamble includes:

```
\usepackage[outputdir=out]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{mathematica}
```

The error arises at the line when a `minted` enviroment is first used, irrespective of whether that particular `minted` environment uses a mathematica-based formatting.

Up until a month ago an almost identical code and setup had given no issues, but I faced a `biber`-`biblatex` compatability issue today and so updated a number of things, including my MacTeX distribution, just prior to this issue appearing.

I am compiling using `lualatex` from the MacTeX distribution on MacOS, but the same issue persists when compiling with `latex` as well.

Referring to the accepted answer at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42793/highlighting-mathematica-code-in-latex-document, I installed `pygments-mathematica` using pip. This had worked for me previously. I also have `pygments` installed using homebrew. I did uninstall and reinstall both of them to try and fix the issue, to no avail.

The issue persists compiling in VSCode, through TexShop, or from the terminal. I have tried locating the `mathematica` folder in `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages` and copying it to the location where I am compiling the `.tex` file, but this does not seem to have an effect either. I have also checked that `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages` is in fact in the path. To be sure I have also attempted adding it to the front of the path and then compiling the `.tex` file:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages:$PATH
lualatex --shell-escape --output-directory=out thesis.tex
```

The same issue persists.

Any advice is welcome. Please let me know if there is anything else I can share.

Comment: you should always first test without `-output-directory` not all tools understand this option.

Comment: You could try the default style with the default mathematica lexer, i.e., remove the `\usemintedstyle` line and use `\begin{minted}{mathematica}`.

Comment: @daleif `--output-directory` was working perfectly prior to this issue. Nevertheless, I did try without it as well, but the same issue persisted.

Comment: @Marijn That does work, and could suffice as a backup, but it does not have syntax highlighting, so I much prefer making the `pygments-mathematica` module work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, it turns out, was not with the TeX side of things, but with `pygments`. Running `pygmentize -L "styles"` showed me that `mathematica` was not a recognised style, though it should have been.

I decided to remove all traces of `pygments` from my system (specifically from the `/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages` directory) and reinstall both `pygments` and `pygments-mathematica` using `pip`. This worked:

```
❯ pygmentize -L "styles"
Pygments version 2.17.2, (c) 2006-2023 by Georg Brandl, Matthäus Chajdas and contributors.

Styles:
~~~~~~~
* abap:
...
* zenburn:
    Low contrast Zenburn style.
* mathematica:
    
* mathematicanotebook:
```

And subsequently, the `.tex` file also compiled with no issues.